# SciPy storing a sparse matrix with default value different from 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I don't know much about the internal representation of a sparse matrix in SciPy
But from my very basic understandings the zeros are compressed, while non-zero references are saved along with their position inside the matrix.

What I need is to replace the compressed number (zero) with another one.

My poblem arise from the fact that I start from a normal sparse matrix and then I subtract a constant `c` from it, thus I come with a matrix whose most common number is `-c`.

In conclusion is it possible to store this new matrix as a sparse one? I need a SciPy based solution, but all the suggestions are accepted.

Comment: `pandas` sparse accepts various `fill-values`, but the `scipy` sparse is strictly 0.  Do you want to subtract `c` from all elements of the matrix (0 or not) or just from the non-zero terms?

Comment: @hpaulj I need to subtract `c` from all the elements, then I will perform an SVD with SciPy.

Comment: Unless you are using some function in the `sparse.linalg` package, your matrix has to be dense.  You may need to ask a new question focusing on that `svd` function.

Comment: Luckily `svds` is from that package. Thanks for the advice.